# Opencart - display products with specific option

Tags: filter, opencart

I'm using opencart 1.5.5.1 with vQMOD
Is there any possibility or some extension like filter, to show products with specific option.

For example i have a shop with clothes. In option i save size like XS,S,L.
If i click some button like XS i want to see only clothes with XS size option.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link

You Can Use Filters

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-filters-in-opencart--cms-22594